# Why am I unable to boot Ubuntu after motherboard change?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, raid, ahci

I have a Dell XPS 15 laptop and I had my motherboard replaced. After that I am no longer able to dual-boot Windows and Ubuntu. Of course I disabled Secure boot in BIOS. The problem is:

- if I set SATA mode to RAID on, the GRUB bootloader loads correctly, but if I select Ubuntu (no matter which kernel or if it's recovery mode or not), I get the error:

```
Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems:
 - Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
 - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
 - Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! /dev/disk/by-uuid/920903aa-762f-40d2-8126-87f4b0e6f975 does not exist. Dropping to a shell!
```

- if I try AHCI mode, I'm not even able to access GRUB boot menu, as I get Dell system check screen right away and after that it starts recovery process.

I'd really appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 2):

When this happens, it is usually a problem in `initramfs`. You can fix it like this:

0. Boot from a LiveUSB/DVD
1. Open a Terminal
2. Perform the following commands:

   ```
   $ sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
   $ sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
   $ sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
   $ sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
   $ sudo chroot /mnt
   $ update-initramfs -u
   $ update-grub
   $ reboot
   ```

Be sure to replace `/dev/sda1` with the actual device name of the system partition, otherwise "bad things will happen". The issue comes down to what `initramfs` is expecting to find when it boots. Replacing a motherboard, even if it's with another of the exact same model, is nothing to sneeze at. This would be like replacing a person's lungs with a set from a donor. Sure, they work the same ... but *they're not the same*. Updating `initramfs` is a good way to ensure this issue does not prevent a machine from booting after parts are replaced/upgraded.